# Run action in model by checkbox checked in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models: `Project` and `Account`.

I want user to check, if he want to create a new `Account`, when creating `Project` or not, so I have a `check_box_tag` in form for creating new project.

```
<%= form_for @project, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    .
    .
    <%= check_box_tag('create_account_checkbox') %> Create new account
    .
    .
<% end %>
```

and in `project.rb` model I have this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_account
  .
  .
  .
  def create_account
    if #Here I need to add smth like `check_box.checked?`
      Account.create(:name => name, ...and so on)
    end
  end
end
```

What I need to add to these parts of code to make them working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this — one way:

Add an mattr_accessor (rails 4) to your Project, which you can set using your checkbox:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :create_account

  after_create :create_account if: :requested_account?

  def requested_account?
    create_account
  end

  ...
end
```

Now just be careful your checkbox returns something that will be interpreted as a boolean.

(i haven't tested this — there may be an issue with the mattr_accessor being unset post save..gotta check on that)

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.7. Are there any ways to do it there?

Comment: search the API for attr_accessor, and if this is a new project, you should be using Rails 4!